# Laravel :query select 'as' not working with where or have

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to get nearby companies
here is my query

```
$lat = 21.41241750000001;
$long = 39.23094140625001;
return
    $this->model->select('id', 'lat', 'long', DB::raw(sprintf(
    '(6371 * acos(cos(radians(%1$.7f)) * cos(radians(`lat`)) * cos(radians(`long`) - radians(%2$.7f)) + sin(radians(%1$.7f)) * sin(radians(`lat`)))) AS `distance`',
    $lat,
    $long
)))
    ->having('distance', '<', 50)
    ->orderBy('distance', 'asc')
    ->paginate();
```

and always get me

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in
> 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `companies`
> having `distance` = 50)

my table schema

```
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                                               | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(10) unsigned                                   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name_en           | varchar(191)                                       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name_ar           | varchar(191)                                       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| search_keywords   | text                                               | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status            | enum('REJECTED','ACCEPTED','PENDING','DUPLICATED') | NO   | MUL | PENDING |                |
| rejection_reason  | text                                               | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| industry          | varchar(191)                                       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| website           | varchar(191)                                       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city_id           | int(10) unsigned                                   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| zone_id           | int(10) unsigned                                   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| size              | int(11)                                            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lat               | varchar(191)                                       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| long              | varchar(191)                                       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| formatted_address | text                                               | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| street            | varchar(191)                                       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| building          | varchar(191)                                       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| floor_no          | int(10) unsigned                                   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| landmarks         | varchar(255)                                       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| company_id        | int(10) unsigned                                   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at        | timestamp                                          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at        | timestamp                                          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Note: if I do the query without have and order the distance returned and calculated
any help?

Comment: can you post your "companies" table structure here?

Comment: id | int(10) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
 | name_en | varchar(191) | NO | | NULL | 
 | city_id | int(10) unsigned | YES | | NULL | 
 | lat | varchar(191) | NO | MUL | NULL | | | long | varchar(191) –

Comment: sorry can't format the comment @TariqImtinan

Comment: try remove quotation marks like;
`AS distance`

Comment: @ElektaKode same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I adapted my code for your context. You may try addSelect.
I think this code is a starting point for your solution:

```
$lat = 21.41241750000001;
$long = 39.23094140625001;
Companies::addSelect(['distance' => DB::raw(sprintf('(6371 * acos(cos(radians(%1$.7f)) * cos(radians(`lat`)) * cos(radians(`long`) - radians(%2$.7f)) + sin(radians(%1$.7f)) * sin(radians(`lat`)))) AS `distance`',
                      $lat,
                      $long))
                      ])                    
          ->havingRaw('distance < 50')
          ->orderBy('distance', 'asc')
          ->get();
```

I couldn't test it; Send us feedback!

Comment: No it did not work with me but I get it to work but it not the best solution 
I used `get` instead of  `paginate`

Comment: I just edited to get() instead paginate(). Why is it not a good solution?

Answer (score -1):

the problem with me was in `paginate` so I used `get` but I don't know why so I any one can explain it will be wonderful